# Cumulative data instead of Averaged after concatenating

Tags: group-by, concatenation, scatter-plot

In 1 day, PV output is measured every 2 mins, for one setup. I have 3 setups in one sheet, so 1 column timestamp, 2nd column setup 1, 3rd column setup 2, 4th column setup 3. And this is done everyday for 18 months.

I want to process data to get the average value for each setup at each timestamp. E.g. at 7am, sum all the PV output measured across 18 months for setup 1, divided by the no. of days to give one value. This is to be done for the whole day. So end result is one day, one averaged value at each timestamp for each setup.

I want to plot a line graph of PV output against time for setup 1, and do this same thing for the other 2 setups.

I have concatenated the data. Merged and dropped columns as some headers for my setups have typos so theyre recognised differently.I've tried to plot one setup (pv-green) - PV output against time. But the graph comes out weird, more cumulative than 1 data at each time point. Not sure whats the issue. Code below

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import os
excel_dir = '/kaggle/input/pv-updated/PV'

first_file = '/kaggle/input/pv-updated/PV/1 Apr 2021.csv'
PV_2122 = pd.read_csv(first_file)

for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input/pv-updated'):
    for filename in filenames:
        name = str(os.path.join(excel_dir, filename))  # Corrected from first_file to filename
        if name.endswith('.csv'):
           file_path = pd.read_csv(name)
           PV_2122 = pd.concat([file_path, PV_2122], ignore_index=True) 

# merge duplicate columns for pv_green
 PV_2122['pv_green'] = PV_2122['PV-Green'].combine_first(PV_2122['PV Green'])
 PV_2122['pv_green'] = PV_2122['PV Green'].combine_first(PV_2122['pv_green'])

 # drop the old columns
drop_green = ['PV-Green', 'PV Green']
PV_2122.drop(drop_green, axis=1, inplace=True)
PV_2122.head()

average_pv_green = PV_2122.groupby(['TimeStamp'])['pv_green'].mean()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(PV_2122)

marker_size = 0.1

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

# Use 'o' as a marker for scatter plot
plt.scatter(df['TimeStamp'], df['pv_green'], label='PV Output', marker='.', color='b', s=marker_size)

plt.xlabel('TimeStamp')
plt.ylabel('pv_green')
plt.title('PV green')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=5)  # Adjust x-axis label font size

plt.legend()  # Display legend

plt.show()
```

Comment: `average_pv_green = PV_2122.groupby(['TimeStamp'])['pv_green'].mean()` and then `df = pd.DataFrame(PV_2122)`

Comment: @MatBailie nope it produces the same thing. Also may i clarify, whats the difference between that and my code?

Comment: I was showing you your mistake.  You assign the averages to `average_pv_green` but then don't use it.

Comment: OMG @MatBailie thanks a million. I'd replaced both with df = pd.DataFrame(['average_pv_green'], ['TimeStamp']) and plt.scatter(df['TimeStamp'], df['average_pv_green'], label='PV Output', marker='.', color='b', s=marker_size) but I got a keyerror saying "TimeStamp"